# sprite collision cocos2d. collision per frame

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

ok so i have two sprites colliding, 'player' and 'rock' this is what i want, when a collision takes place i want (INT) lives to increment by +1 so lives++

however a collision takes place in every frame! so (int) lives equals to a number over 100!

how can i make (int) lives increment by +1 every time the sprites collide? not every frame they collide?

here is the code i have used

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    [livesLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", lives]];

    CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(
                                   player.position.x - (player.contentSize.width), 
                                   player.position.y - (player.contentSize.height), 
                                   player.contentSize.width, 
                                   player.contentSize.height);

    for (CCSprite *rock in rockArray) 
    {
        CGRect rockRect = CGRectMake(
                                   rock.position.x - (rock.contentSize.width), 
                                   rock.position.y - (rock.contentSize.height), 
                                   rock.contentSize.width, 
                                   rock.contentSize.height);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, rockRect)) 
        {
            lives++;  
        }                       
    }
}
```

the above code is when 'rock' and player collide, lives is being increment by 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement some kind of basic collision detection in a case like yours, what you should do is managing a list of all pairs that have had a collision; when two sprites collide, you add them to the list only if they are not already there.

Also have a look at [this post by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial), although the case represented is not analogous to yours.

Another approach is using chipmunk or Box2D just for collision detections. Again, you can find a tutorial about the latter on [R.W. site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `lives` to increment but then stop incrementing until the sprites separate and are no longer collided, then they collide again and lives increments once more.

So just add a variable so that once lives is incremented, you have a `BOOL` switched on; add this BOOL to your `if` condition so that lives is not incremented unless the bool is switched off. Switch off the bool with another test that determines when they are *not* intersecting.

Comment: thanks, i seem to have a slight understanding of what your saying, any chance you could show an example with code?